# MongoDB tries to load non existing file while using git alias with db name in parameter

Tags: git, mongodb, alias

I created a working mongoDB script for setting up basic data in my database
I also created the following git alias :

```
initDB = !mongo ${1-defaultDataBaseName} \"script.js\"
```

the goal was to have an alias to apply the script to the database send in the parameter.
by exemple. calling

```
git initDB foo
```

would call the script for the database "foo".
it work, but also raise an expected error :
after connecting to "foo" and loading the file "script.js", it try to load the file "foo", fail (because the file obviously do not exist), and log the following error.

```
MongoDB shell version : 3.2.1
loading file : script.js
script success (printed by script.js)
loading file : foo
2016-08-16T10:28:38.861-0400 E - [main] file [foo] doesn't exist
failed to load: foo
fatal: While expanding alias 'initDB': 'mongo ${1-defaultDBName} "script.js"': No such file or directory
```

can someone explain me why and how to prevent the code to try to open a file with the same name as the database.

When I do not use parameter (and use the default name), there is no error.